# How do I properly write this conditionals in a Loop for Common Lisp?

Tags: loops, while-loop, common-lisp

```
(defun lista-n (a b c)   
  (loop repeat 10
        for x = (+ a c) then (+ x c)                            
                             (while (/= x a) 
                                    do (if (> x b) 
                                       (- x b))   ;then               
                             collect x))
```

I am new to Common Lisp and I need to know which is the proper syntax for this Loop.

I want to be able to obtain a cyclical list  such as 
(lista-n 0 5 2) => (0 2 4 1 3 5)

A list between 0 and 5 by 2. If  Number > 5 then Number - 5.

Comment: You might want to increase readability by indenting your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Code problems

Contrary to most constructs in Common Lisp, LOOP's syntax is purposely using few parentheses. The `(while ...)` part is not appropriate in this context. Also, you could use `until (= x a)`, which I find more readable. Have a look at [§22. LOOP for Black Belts](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/loop-for-black-belts.html).

Also, `(- x b)` only computes a subtraction, but does not affect any variable. If you want to decrement `x`, like `x -= b` in C, use `(decf x b)`.

The name of your function and variables are also not helpful to understand what is supposed to happen.

Finally, your code might not behave appropriately if you have a very large step, because simply computing `(- x b)` might give a result which is still greater than `b`. Also, there might be problems with negative inputs.

#### First attempt

I tried to take care of all corner cases I cound think about, like negative steps, etc. There is also a test which prevents infinite loops by checking if the current number already exists in the list. The check is linear in time, which makes the whole loop quadratic. For very large lists, this could be a 
problem.

```
(defun circular-range (from to step)
  (loop
     with low = (min from to) and high = (max from to)
     with divisor = (- high low)
     for value = from then (+ wrapped step)
     for wrapped = (if (<= low value high) 
                       value
                       (+ low (mod (- value low) divisor)))
     until (member wrapped numbers)
     collect wrapped into numbers
     until (= wrapped to)
     finally (return numbers)))
```

#### Using more maths

Thanks to maths, it possible to know the size of the period from the range being covered and the step: [Progressions modulo *n*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1861199/progressions-modulo-n). That allows to remove some checks, in particular the list of already seen numbers.

```
(defun circular-range (from to step)
  (loop
     with low = (min from to) and high = (max from to)
     with range = (- high low)
     with period = (/ range (gcd range step))
     repeat (1+ period)
     for value = from then (+ wrapped step)
     for first = t then nil
     for wrapped = (if (<= low value high) 
                       value
                       (+ low (mod (- value low) range)))
     when (or first (/= wrapped from))
       collect wrapped))
```

We need however to repeat once more to satisfy the specification and collect the `to` value, except when that value is equal to `from`.

#### Tests

The following results are identical with both versions.

```
(circular-range 0 5 0)
=> (0)

(circular-range 0 5 2)
=> (0 2 4 1 3 5)

(circular-range 0 -5 2)
=> (0 -3 -1 -4 -2)

(circular-range 10 -5 2)
=> (10 -3 -1 1 3 5 7 9 -4 -2 0 2 4 6 8)

(circular-range 10 50 13)
=> (10 23 36 49 22 35 48 21 34 47 20 33 46 19 32 45 18 31 44 17 30 43 16 29 42 15
   28 41 14 27 40 13 26 39 12 25 38 11 24 37 50)

(circular-range 30 35 -2)
=> (30 33 31 34 32)

(circular-range 30 30 -5)
=> (30)
```

Comment: when the WITH clauses and FOR clauses are independent, then you can mark this with AND: FOR a from b to c and d from to f... WITH foo = 1 and bar = 2 ....